# PIG filter by string

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to filter by a string but it fails. How do I filter by String? I tried looking here http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#comparison but matches only works for regular expressions.

```
f = FILTER finished_set by item is not matches '.*0000000000000.*';
```

> ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer - exception during parsing: Error
>   during parsing.   mismatched
>   input 'matches' expecting NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f = FILTER finished_set BY NOT(item  MATCHES '.*0000000000000.*');
```

Comment: `mismatched input 'not' expecting LEFT_PAREN `